# How to add in MySQL more than one column which also will remove duplicates?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique

How to make something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `people` ADD UNIQUE (`name`, `hair_color`)
```

which also will remove duplicates from table `people`

f.e. I have data:

```
 `name` | `hair_color`
--------|--------------
 'John' | 'brown'
 'Paul' | 'brown'
 'Paul' | 'brown'
 'Paul' | 'gray'
```

and after operation I want to have UNIQUE KEY in table and only 2 Pauls (one wtih brown and one with gray hair).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a nice little hack for this. You can prefix pretty much any command with `IGNORE` to make it ignore errors and let it work "some way":

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `people` ADD UNIQUE (`name`, `hair_color`)
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no single operation to do that. You need to first delete the duplicates and then you can add the UNIQUE constraint</strike>

The general approach to do this (if your table is not too big):

```
CREATE TABLE people_new (name varchar(20), hair_color varchar(20))
SELECT DISTINCT name, hair_color
FROM people;

DROP TABLE people;

ALTER TABLE people_new RENAME TO people;

ALTER TABLE people ADD UNIQUE (name, hair_color);
```

Comment: Your solution is nice and works in every database, but it's not needed for MySQL. With the `IGNORE` modifier you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint without making it unique first.

Comment: Didn't know the IGNORE would actually delete the conflicting rows. So that is indeed that "single" operation.

Comment: Also problem is I have more than 2 columns in `people` and doing it that way I'll lost them

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `IGNORE` keyword and it'll get rid of duplicates in the process:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `people` ADD UNIQUE (`name`, `hair_color`)
```